# Equal height rows in flex-direction: column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex layout with two flex items, displayed as rows (`flex-direction: column`). The items should have a minimum height but they should maintain the same height it one of them needs to grow. See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/958vxhox/) and decrease the width of the result pane; this forces the second `.component` element to increase its height, but the height of the first `.component` element remains the same.

Is it possible to force the flex items to maintain the same height? Please note that the main thing in this is the stacking of the two `.component` elements, which I couldn't achieve without `flex-direction: column`; `flex-direction: row` would have made the same height possible but the stacking does not work.

Here is the result of what I have so far:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: stretch;
}
.component {
  min-height: 300px;
}
.left {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
.right {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: -250px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="component left">

  </div>
  <div class="component right">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed orci scelerisque, scelerisque enim at, ullamcorper ipsum. Cras eget sapien mi. Aliquam ultrices, ligula ut mollis maximus, ligula massa imperdiet libero, at faucibus mauris ante non
      magna. Sed ex lacus, efficitur sit amet neque ut, venenatis hendrerit libero. Suspendisse ornare orci mi. Nulla iaculis egestas libero, eu tincidunt urna tristique et. Quisque nec odio non elit molestie facilisis.
    </p>
    <p>
      Vestibulum scelerisque justo urna, a semper nisi sollicitudin in. Cras congue enim eu euismod semper. Proin consequat gravida felis, quis tincidunt massa pulvinar quis. Morbi nec diam eget orci vestibulum malesuada. Sed volutpat metus eget mattis commodo.
      Nulla facilisi. Praesent lectus mauris, consequat eu varius vitae, cursus vitae leo. Vivamus sagittis lacinia tortor eu ullamcorper. Integer eget velit magna. Duis vestibulum molestie posuere.
    </p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not totally sure what layout you want to achieve. Do you want the two components to be side by side with equal height, or stacked on top of each other with equal height? The fiddle shows the two components overlapping for me. ... So do you mean stacked on top of each other instead?

Comment: @elfwyn the overlapping is intended and is the most important part of the layout. That's why I set all the margins. They both have a minimum height of `300px`. The height of the `.right` component will change according to it's content. When this happens, the `.left' component should also change it's size.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The flex equal height columns feature – which is the result of `align-items: stretch`, a default setting of a flex container – applies only to flex items on the same row.

It doesn't work for items in a multi-line flex container. This behavior is defined in the spec:

> [**6. Flex Lines**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-lines)
>
> In a multi-line flex container (even one with only a single line), the
>   cross size of each line is the minimum size necessary to contain the
>   flex items on the line (after alignment due to `align-self`), and the
>   lines are aligned within the flex container with the `align-content`
>   property.

In other words, when there are multiple lines in a row-based flex container, the height of each line (the *"cross size"*) is the *"minimum size necessary to contain the flex items on the line"*.

In addition, because `align-items: stretch` works along the cross-axis, the equal height columns feature is useless in `flex-direction: column`, where the cross-axis is horizontal.

To achieve equal height columns/rows across multiple lines consider a Javascript solution.

---

However, without knowing much about your overall objective, here's a simple way to achieve equal height rows in your current layout:

> Add duplicate content in both divs. In the `.component.left` div, use `visibility: hidden`.

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/958vxhox/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forgot to take out the 'align-items` rule after trying to overlap columns. This might have been a _XY problem_. I should have stated the desired output (overlapping children & content aware container) and not ask about haw to fix a flexbox issue. Nevertheless, your answer provided a solution to my question. After some consideration I ditched flexbox and found a solution using pseudo elements. One needs to ask the right question...

Answer (score 7):

You can just wrap those flexbox columns in another flexbox that's a row, there's no reason you can't have items be both flexboxes and flex items.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}

#container .col {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="col">
    <a href="">asdf</a>
    <a href="">asdf</a>
    <a href="">asdf</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <a href="">asdf</a>
    <a href="">asdf</a>
    <a href="">asdf</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1dp87bm2/1/