# Bootstrap row - force the same height of divs when collapsed on small devices

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to force the same height of both `divs` in a bootstrap `row` when the row collapses on small device.

So the code is pretty much this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
         content
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6>
         content
    </div>
</div>
```

The bottom picture tells a thousand words: the top part of the image is what happens on bigger devices: both divs have same height which is what I want - but when I open the page on a small device, the green div's height is way lower than the red ones. How can I force the same height when the row collapses?

[image: What happens:]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equal height rows in flex-direction: column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37938614/equal-height-rows-in-flex-direction-column)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to heights to be dynamic or can they be a set height? If so, you could force the height by giving your divs an id and setting the css for devices of a certain size like so:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" id="row1">
         content
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" id="row2">
         content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
    {

    #row1{
    height: 300px;
    }

    #row2{
    height: 300px;
    }

    }
```

Comment: That would work, but the height can not be set. It should depend on the content of the div.

Comment: So is your issue that the content is shrinking? Or should the green column inherit it's height based on the red one? I assume the content in each is different (and perhaps has different heights)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want red's div to inherit green's div (siblings) height.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new class (example: content1,content2), then manually set the dimensions you require in a css file.

```css
.content1 {
   background-color: red;
   height: 400px;
}

.content2 {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 content1">
         content1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 content2">
         content2
    </div>
</div>
```